# Bancos de dados em Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenho o Oracle 11g instalado em minha maquina.
No Oracle tenho configurado uma conexão local.
Nessa conexão local tenho varias tabelas.

Gostaria de nessa mesma conexão local, criar outro "banco de dados" onde eu pudesse criar novas tabelas.

Minha pergunta é:

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Se existe, como posso fazer para criar os novos bancos?

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Dê uma olhada na [help] em especial no link [ask]. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para deixá-la mais clara.

Comment: Obrigado @Caputo. Refiz minha pergunta, espero que ela esteja mais entendível.

Comment: @johhny - Em que user(owner) você criou suas tabelas ? Não precisa de outra Instância na minha opinião (m parece um BD apenas para estudo) para criar outro USER dar os GRANTS ecessários e criar as tabelase outros objetos.

Comment: @Motta, obrigado pela ajuda. Consegui me localizar.

Comment: @Motta Considere adicionar uma resposta com as dicas que você deu no comentário, assim o usuário poderá marcá-la como certa e ela fica mais visível para quem visitar o site depois.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa de outra Instância na minha opinião (me parece um BD apenas para estudo) basta criar outro USER dar os GRANTS necessários e criar as tabelas e e outros objetos.

Criação de usuário (Oracle)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm

Grants (Oracle)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm

Caso queira saber mais sobre instâncias 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/startup.htm#CNCPT005

Não se recomenda aqui links, mas creio que estes não "quebrarão" tão cedo.